# Redirect https://no-www to https://www on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk App (Ruby on Rails):

`http://www -> https://www` [works]

`http://non-www -> https://www` [works]

`https://non-www -> https://www` [does not work]

Answer (score 0):

Add a route that looks something like this:

```
# Redirect example.com => www.example.com
constraints(host: /^example\.com/i) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect { |params, _req| "https://www.example.com/#{params[:path]}" }, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Comment: Where should we put this?

Comment: It was in `config/routes.rb`, at the top I believe.